# Data is not inserted in oracle database from VB6

Tags: oracle, vb6

I want to add data in FingerData table in oracle database from VB6 . That is why , I have the following code .

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As String

cn = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=fingerprintdata;User ID=fingerprintdata;Data Source=10.11.201.84;Persist Security Info=True"
conn.Open cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "FINGERDATA", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable


s = StrConv(b, vbUnicode)
rs.AddNew
rs!UserName = strName
rs!fingerdata = "123"
rs!key = "Testing 9001"
rs.Update
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

But the data is not inserted . What is the error ? How can I insert data in oracle database from vb6 ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Can you post a little more to help a potential answerer? Literally one million things could be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Please use this statement:

rs.Open "FINGERDATA", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic